# Redirecting another domain to an existing drupal installation's subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, drupal-7

I've been trying to solve a problem for the past few hours. I am desperate for help!

I have two domains:

```
rd1.example.com/drupal
rd2.example.com
```

I have a drupal installation in rd1.example.com/drupal/

Further, I started creating content on drupal in a url alias: rd1.example.com/drupal/rd2/

What I want to do is used the second website to point to that specific content within my drupal installation:

```
rd2.example.com -> rd1.example.com/drupal/rd2/
```

I don't want it to be a redirect but an internal hidden redirect. The user will think that they are on rd2.example.com.

I've switched rd2.example.com to point to the directory where drupal is installed. I've been trying to edit the rewriterules on drupal's .htaccess but with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my rules so far:

```
#Existing settings
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^rd2\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

#New rules to accomodate for rd2.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rd2\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/rd2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* /rd2/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Does the `/drupal/rd2/` directory actually exist? Or is it a virtual path that's supposed to be served up by drupal?

Comment: It is a virtual path served up by drupal. Internally drupal knows to which page this should point to. It does not exist physically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal relies on the server variables to process its request. That means when you internally rewrite to `/rd2/$0`, drupal doesn't know what to do with that. You'll need to reverse proxy *from the rd2` subdomain instead. So leave drupal the way it is, then on the rd2.example.com document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rd2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rd1.example.com/drupal/rd2/$1 [L,P]
```

This will only work if you have mod_proxy loaded on your server, otherwise nothing will happen. Mod_proxy can only be turned on through your server's config. You could also setup the reverse proxy from the vhost config for the rd2 subdomain:

```
ProxyPass / http://rd1.example.com/drupal/rd2/
```

Comment: Yeap worked like I charm. I used the proxypass since it seems to be safer rather than activating in apache's config the config.

Answer (score 0):

Beside of proxy, you may also consider to use a symbolic link that made by a shell command like so:

```
ln -s /path/to/rd1 /path/to/drupal/rd2
```

More details is explained in [*Multi-site - Sharing the same code base*](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site)